# why is openvpn.service running by default?

Tags: openvpn

I notice that openvpn.service is active on my 19.10 machine and I'm wondering what service it is providing? What parts of the system depend on it?

I understand the function of VPN, I'm wondering why this service is running when I'm not using a VPN. Is Ubuntu using some of its features for some other off-label network task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ExpressVPN. I just contacted their support who have informed me that openvpn.service is a part of their system that runs in the background even when I am not explicitly running the service.

So that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to connect to VPN servers. It probably came in with the Network Manager program, since NM has configuration GUI for it.

You ask why it is installed. I don't mean to insult you intelligence, but here goes.

A VPN is a server to which you at attach for security reasons. It locks your system to use a DNS server that is approved for purposes of VPN admin. It is protection against danger you will browse http://espn.com and the name server gives you back address for a porno site. Also protects you from monitoring by a dns server. If you are in hotel, say, there is danger your name lookups are monitored by hotel wifi. Use vpn to protect yourself in cases like that.  So don't remove openvpn.

If you like putting your finger in a light socket, you can just try to remove the package. synaptic would make that easy. Or in terminal

$ sudo dpkg --remove openvpn

It will tell you what other dependent packages would be removed.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you. I'll clarify my question. I don't feel my intelligence insulted at all. I'm far too arrogant to make that an easy task for anyone -- in my view attempts to insult my intelligence tend to reflect badly on the fool who's trying. Now I do know about VPNs and use one that I pay for but I've found Ubuntu over-cautious in its assumptions about users' requirements, and undercautious in its off-label coupling of services and libraries . Hence my question. Good info from you so I give you a vote but not the answer I'm looking for so no tick this time.

Comment: See the answer I just posted. Duh! I should've thought of asking ExpressVPN first? Stupid  intelligence!

Comment: The dpkg command would have told you ExpressVPN was depending on openvpn. Let me know if that is wrong

Comment: @pauljohn32: I reached here because even I saw openvpn active on my system, and I don't use VPN. But just like OP, I couldn't understand from your answer, why openvpn needs to be running. Can't my computer make a connection to the internet securely without a VPN? Even if network manager has an option for VPN, why does the openvpn service need to be active all the time? Couldn't it just be made active whenever I want to use a VPN?